# WPF Command Bindings Using Alternate Namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command

All,

I have defined the following

```
xmlns:default="clr-namespace:dotDiff2013" 
xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:dotDiff2013.Commands"
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="commands:ComparerCommands.NewComparison"
                        Executed="NewComparison"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

where in the namespace `dotDiff2013.Commands` I have

```
namespace dotDiff2013.Commands 
{             
    public class ComparerCommands
    {
        static ComparerCommands()
        {
            InputGestureCollection inputs = new InputGestureCollection();
            inputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+N"));
            newComparison = new RoutedUICommand(
                "New Document Comparison", "NewComparison", typeof(ComparerCommands), inputs);
        }

        private static RoutedUICommand newComparison;
        public static RoutedUICommand NewComparison
        {
            get { return newComparison; }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following errors

---

[image: Errors]

---

**What am I doing wrong?**

I am new to WPF and this error is confusing as from the book I have I have done the right thing. Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact you are binding to a static property on a non-static class?

Comment: My suggestion is to first make sure you can do your binding from the code behind and then attempt to move it to xaml. CommandBinding NewComparerCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
    commands:ComparerCommands.NewComparison, NewComparisonCommandHandler, CanExecuteNewComparisonHandler);

// Add the CommandBinding to the root Window.
RootWindow.CommandBindings.Add(NewComparerCommandBinding);

Answer (score 0):

use the {x:Static commands:ComparerCommands.NewComparison} syntax

Comment: Have you removed all the other errors? Most changes to code only gets recognized by the designer if the assembly is successfully recompiled. What does the NewComparison method look like?